# Extract items from json format

Tags: python, json, extract, jsonschema

I am trying to extract data from json format, which also contains list of dicts. But when I access it then it shows `None`.

**What I am trying to do:-**

I am trying to get `content` from this below resonse

code.py

```
def extract():
    res = {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
      "anyOf": [{
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "response": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "content": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "id": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "title": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "id",
                    "title"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "content",
              "response"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }

    # When I try this then it shows an error
    json_ext = json.loads(res)
    print(json_ext['anyOf[0].properties'])
```

It returns as error

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

I have also tried using

```
def deep_get_imps(data, key: str):
    split_keys = re.split("[\\[\\]]", key)
    out_data = data
    for split_key in split_keys:
        if split_key == "":
            return out_data
        elif isinstance(out_data, dict):
            out_data = out_data.get(split_key)
        elif isinstance(out_data, list):
            try:
                sub = int(split_key)
            except ValueError:
                return None
            else:
                length = len(out_data)
                out_data = out_data[sub] if -length <= sub < length else None
        else:
            return None
    return out_data


def deep_get(dictionary, keys):
    return reduce(deep_get_imps, keys.split("."), dictionary)
```

**AS**

```
print(deep_get(res, "anyOf[0].items[0]"))
```

But it returns none, It is still not getting `content` response.

I have many times but it is still not working. Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: try `json.load(res)` in your first example. the one you're using is for loading json objects from their string representation. Also, you'll need to change the way you're getting the element you want to `print(json_ext['anyOf'][0]['properties'])`. I highly advise you to read up on [dicts](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) and [json](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) at w3schools

Comment: As a note, it's bad to use the URI `http://json-schema.org/schema#` as your JSON Schema dialect URI. It's far better to specify the specific version you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object, `res`, is a so called dict and that's why your code throws the `TypeError` when you call `json_ext = json.loads(res)`, since `loads` only works on strings of characters and similar types.
What you probably wanted to do is more like this:

```py
def extract():
    res = {
          ...  # shortened for readability
    }
    print(res["anyOf"][0]["items"]["properties"]["content"])
```